# how to dynamically set ExpansionPanel expanded state

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In my React app, I have a search bar and ExpansionPanel (or Accordion). I have a list of items grouped by category using the ExpansionPanel. The user could toggle the selection of each groups, as well as individual items. The user could also use search bar to search items. I would like the ExpansionPanel of a group be expanded (1) if the group's state is checked or indeterminate (2) if the group is unchecked, but has some items match the search text. Following is a brief summary of the code. So far I could only use defaultExpanded to set the initial expanded state of the ExpansionPanel. This would not satisfy the second requirement. If I use the expanded instead of defaultExpanded, I won't be able to toggle the panel. How to dynamically set the expanded of the panel?

```
<Box>
        <TextField
          fullWidth
          label="search"
          variant="outlined"
          value={searchText}
          onChange={(e) => setSearchText(e.target.value)}
        />
</Box>
<Box>
{filterItemGroups(searchText, itemGroups).map(
    (itemGroup)=>(
    <ExpansionPanel
                key={itemGroup.id}
                defaultExpanded={
                  isItemGroupCheckedOrIndeterminate(itemGroup) ||
                  searchText
                }
    >
    <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMore />}>
    ...
    </ExpansionPanelSummary>
    <ExpansionPanelDetails>
    {filterItems(searchText, items, groupId).map(item=>
    ...)
    }
    </ExpansionPanelDetails>

    )
)
}</ExpansionPanel>
</Box>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use expanded prop and add onChange and change the state of ExpanasionPanel to close or open it. Also add state object to keep track of multiple accordians and make state default to true. So, if text matches and expansion.panel1 is true then only it shows and you can programmatically make expansion.panel1 false. Below example is just an idea not an implementaion.

```
const [expansion, setExpansion] = useState({
 panel1: true,
 panel2: true,
 ...
})

<ExpansionPanel
   key={itemGroup.id}
   expanded={
     expansion.panel1 ||((isItemGroupCheckedOrIndeterminate(itemGroup) ||
     searchText) && expansion.panel1)
   }
   onChange={() => // make expansion.panel1 toggle}
>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked most of the cases. But I couldn't expand those groups that initially collapsed when there is no search.

Comment: I have updated the code. You can shortcuit the code condition. (I think it will work)